# Linear system with a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have the following exercise:

> Show that if the system $AX = B$  admits a unique solution then $\ker A = \{0\}$.

This is my attempt:

- A linear system $AX = B$, $A \in\mathscr M_\mathbb R(m,n)$, admits a single solution only if $\mathrm{rk}(A) = \mathrm{rk}(A|b) = n$.
- I know that $\ker A = n - \mathrm{rk}(A)$, so $\ker A = n - n = 0$.

Is this proof right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is quite correct. At the end, your should write $\dim(\ker(A))=n-\text{rk}(A)$ instead of $\ker(A)=n-\text{rk}(A)$.

---

By the way, you could also show the contrapositive: if $\ker(A) \neq \{0\}$, pick any non zero vector $v \in \ker(A)$. Then:

- either $AX=B$ has no solution
- either $AX=B$ has at least one solution, say $X_0$. But then, $X_0+v \neq X_0$ is also a solution, since $Av=0$ by assumption. Then there are at least two different solutions.

In all cases, it is not true that $AX=B$ admits a unique solution.